# python MainThread is printed instead of thread-1,-2 when calling from a class

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, threadpool, python-multithreading

When i have moved my method into a class, logging.debug stopped printing thread-#, it now just prints mainthread. How can i get logging.debug to print thread-# for each log

code:

```
class threadTest():
testResult=''
def __init__(self,nThread,nTests,debugOn):

    self.nThread = nThread
    self.nTests = nTests
    self.debugOn = debugOn        

    if debugOn == 1:
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',)

@classmethod
def test(cls):

        if debugOn == 1: logging.debug('Starting')

        ...do something...

        if debugOn == 1: logging.debug('Exiting')        
        time.sleep(1)

arguments=sys.argv

nThread = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv)>1 else 1
nTests = int(sys.argv[2]) if len(sys.argv)>2 else 1
debugOn = int(sys.argv[3]) if len(sys.argv)>3 else 0
myThread = threadTest(nThread,nTests,debugOn)

x=1

while x <= nThread:
    thread='Thread-'+str(x)
    t=threading.Thread(name=thread, target=myThread.test())
    t.start()
    x+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Current output:

```
[DEBUG] (MainThread) Starting
[INFO] (MainThread) Starting new ...
[DEBUG] (MainThread) Exiting
[DEBUG] (MainThread) Starting
[INFO] (MainThread) Starting new ...
[DEBUG] (MainThread) Exiting
```

Expected output:

```
[DEBUG] (Thread-1) Starting
[INFO] (Thread-1) Starting new ...
[DEBUG] (Thread-1) Exiting
[DEBUG] (Thread-2) Starting
[INFO] (Thread-2) Starting new ...
[DEBUG] (Thread-2) Exiting
```

Comment: t=threading.Thread(name=thread, target=myThread.test()) - you are calling test before starting the thread.

Comment: how do you suggest i fix it?

Comment: Alright, i get the threads to be printed by removing () in t=threading.Thread(name=thread, target=myThread.test())

so that it looks like:
t=threading.Thread(name=thread, target=myThread.test)

Comment: Sorry I was late getting back... but, yes, that's what you want to do. You give the function object (`myThread.test`) and let the thread call the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx for @tdelaney for pointing out where the issue was.

```
t=threading.Thread(name=thread, target=myThread.test())
```

was changed to

```
t=threading.Thread(name=thread, target=myThread.test)
```

Thread-1,-2.... now appears